# Number of ways to complete a plan

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I worked on a dynamic programming problem. [Here](https://www.hackerearth.com/fr/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/introduction-to-dynamic-programming-1/practice-problems/algorithm/angry-neighbours/description/) is its link. I have to find the number of ways respecting the constraint that user doesn't go to the Gym for two consecutive days.

```
public int numWays(int n) {
        int[] DP = new int[n + 1];
        DP[0] = 0;
        DP[1] = 2;
        DP[2] = 3;
        for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
            DP[i] = DP[i - 1] + DP[i - 2];
        }
        return DP[n];
    }
```

My solution works, however in case of n is very large, my solution won't perform good as its time complexity is exponential. I want to use matrix multiplication like the one for [Fibonacci solution](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/) but Then I thought that it won't work exactly like that.

How can I improve my solution to have time complexity O(logn)?

Comment: I fail to see the problem with the matrix-based fibonacci solution linked.  That has O(log n) time.  It even has Java code to accomplish it.  The only real difference in your case is that your n is the n+3th fibonacci number so you'll simply have to subtract 3 from n beforehand.